# How can I disable Revmob with code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase, revmob

I would like to have RevMob active for all people in my free game. When they make the in-app purchase to eliminate ads, I'd want to eliminate those RevMob ads.

I first have this code in the AppDelegate, to initiate the session

> [RevMobAds startSessionWithAppID:@"lalala"];

And then in the viewcontroller I have

```
> -(void)viewDidLoad {
> [[RevMobAds session] showBanner];
> [[RevMobAds session] showFullscreen];
> [[RevMobAds session] showPopup];
```

Please help me out or point me in the right direction!!

Comment: You shouldn't make your real appID public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're new to in-app purchase you should check [Introduction to In-App Purchases in iOS 6 Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial) at Ray Wenderlich blog.

Comment: Awesome thanks! As far as, disabling the rev mob ads though how would you do that? Making the in-app purchase is the easy part, but how do I disable the ads?

Comment: Before call the methods to show the ad just check if the user have the in-app.